# How does dividing for a rate gives you a whole remainder?

Tags: fractions, ratio

*Calvin cleans $\frac{3}5$ of his bathroom with $\frac{1}3$ of a bottle.*

*At this rate, what fraction of the bottle of will Calvin use to clean his entire bathroom?*

Khan Academy solve this via $\frac {\frac{1}3}{\frac{3}5} = \frac{5}9$

I don't understand how dividing $\frac{1}3$ into $\frac{3}5$ will result in the remaining $\frac{2}5$ or total sum of $\frac{5}5$ giving it's corrosponding bottle usage. Help me understand the logic?

**Dividing the bottle solution 1/3 into the surface area 3/5, yields the rest of the bottle solution to remaining surface area? That's the area of my confusion**

Comment: Calvin cleans $\frac 15$ of his bathroom using $\frac 19$ of the bottle, so...

Comment: @lulu sure while that tracks, how did you arrive at that answer? The division part doesnt make intuitive sense to me

Comment: Well, what you wrote doesn't make sense.  $\frac {3/1}{3/5}=\frac 15$.  But, generally, we have $\frac 13 : \frac 35$ as $x:1$ so just solve for $x$.

Comment: Corrected my typo. Dividing the bottle solution 1/3 into the surface area 3/5, yields the rest of the bottle solution to remaining surface area? That's the area of my confusion

Comment: Well, post edit, that's the same as my ratio statement.  If the entire bathroom requires $x$ bottles.  Then $n$ bathrooms requires $n\times x$ bottles, and this is true for all positiverational $n$, not just integers. (that is to say, half the bathroom requires $\frac 12$ of a bottle and so on).

Comment: "the rest of the bottle solution to remaining surface area?" Yes that this bottle-to-bathroom ratio should be the same as "Dividing the bottle solution 1/3 into the surface area 3/5".

Comment: What do you mean by "a whole remainder" in your question title?

Answer (score 1):

Think of the part of the room and part of the bottle as a ratio.

Think of the whole room and some part of the bottle as a second ratio.

Assuming Calvin's rate of use does not change, these two ratios should be equal.

So we get 1/3 bottle per 3/5 room is equal to x bottle per 1 room.

This simplifies to just x = 1/3 divided by 3/5